# Trying to get new values when calling class from another class

Tags: java

I am writing a math quiz problem in java that basically asks 10 questions and gives the user 2 
     chances to get the answer right.  The program asks questions based on basic arithmetic in addition, 
     subtraction, division and multiplication.
     My problem is when I run the program, it runs fine but later in the program it asks the same 
     question with the same values.  How do I get the program to use fresh values each and everytime the 
     c lass is called?
     I left the add, subtract, multiply, and divide classes out for now..if you need them please let me 
      know

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.math.*;


public class MathQ {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int credit = 0;
    int firstTry = 0;
    int secondTry = 0;
    int wrong = 0;
    System.out.print("What's your name?");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = sc.next();
    AdditionProblem q1 = new AdditionProblem();
    SubtractionProblem q2 = new SubtractionProblem();
    MultiplicationProblem q3 = new MultiplicationProblem();
    DivisionProblem q4 = new DivisionProblem();

    System.out.println("Nice to meet you , " + name + "!");
    System.out.println("**************MATH CHALLENGE*************");
    System.out.println(
            "This challenge will present you 10 problems in which you will have two chances to answer 
 the question correctly");
    System.out.println(
            "The questions that will be asked will be basic arithmetic ranging from addition, 
 subtraction, multiplication and division");
    System.out.println("You will receive full credit if you answer the question correctly on the 
 first try");
    System.out.println("You will only receive half credit if you answer it correctly on the second 
 try");
    System.out.println("You score will be tallied at the end of the quiz");
    System.out.println("Good luck!");
    System.out.println("---------------------");

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        long rand1 = Math.round((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        // System.out.println(rand1); //for testing random function

        if (rand1 == 1.0) {
            System.out.println("Problem #" + i);
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
            System.out.println(q1.getProblem());

            System.out.println("Type Your Answer Below:");
            Integer ans = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Your answer was: " + ans);
            if (ans == q1.getAnswer()) {
                System.out.println("That is correct!");
                credit = credit + 10;
                firstTry = firstTry + 1;
                System.out.println("Your total points right now is: " + credit);
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                System.out.println("-------------------------");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Sorry that is not correct");
                System.out.println("Lets try again");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(q1.getProblem());
                System.out.println("Type Your Answer:");
                Integer ans1 = sc.nextInt();
                if (ans1 == q1.getAnswer()) {
                    System.out.println("There ya go..good answer");
                    System.out.println("Lets move on");
                    credit = credit + 5;
                    secondTry = secondTry + 1;
                    System.out.println("You total points thus far is: " + credit);
                } else {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Hmmmm.sorry thats still not correct");
                    System.out.println("The correct answer was: " + q1.getAnswer());
                    wrong = wrong + 1;
                    System.out.println("You have " + credit + " points");
                    System.out.println("Lets continue on!");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("-------------------------");
                }

            }
```

Comment: consider splitting you code into methods, where each method does a logical peice of work e.g. getInput or calculateAnswer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the psvm you posted contains the actual code. Should this not be the case, please fill the gaps for me.

There are multiple issues with the code example and I will address them one by one.

You have 4 local attributes q1-q4 with the 4 different instances. Based on the code I see that each of the classes contains one question and one answer. This already limits you to 4 questions tops. There is no way for you to get 10 different questions.

To solve this you have to rethink your approach. I will not go overboard with the OO-Aspect now, as this does not seem to be your goal.
First we have to fix your "static" locals, and add some utility to enable your dynamic questions. Assuming that you do not really care too much about the distribution of types (addition etc) we can remove this separation from the main class. So we add a new class, which we call **ProblemFactory**, and an Interface, which we call **Problem**. Your 4 classes implement **Problem**.

```java
public final class ProblemFactory {

    public static Problem createProblem(){
        long random = Math.round((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        switch(random) {
            case 1:
                return new AdditionProblem();
            case 2:
                return new SubtractionProblem();
                ...
    }
}

public interface Problem {

    public String getProblem();

    public String getAnswer();

}
```

And in your main class you replace the Math.random() line with

```java
Problem problem = ProblemFactory.createProblem();
```

You do not require *if(rand1 == 1.0)* in the main class anymore, and you can remove all but one of these former if-else-blocks. q1-q4 is replaced with the new **problem** variable.

Now your require one last change to your 4 Problem-Classes. I assume you have some type of map in there with 2 strings, where key is the question, and value is the answer. If that is the case your classes could look like this

```java
public class AdditionProblem(){

    private static Map<String, String> questions = createQuestions();

    private String problem;

    private String answer;

    private static Map<String, String> createQuestions() {
        Map<String, String> questions = new HashMap();
        questions.put("24 + 36 + 10", "70");
        //add as many more as you desire, but at least 10 total
        return questions;
    }

    public AdditionProblem(){
        //we first get the number of available questions
        int numberOfQuestions = questions.size();
        //we now generate a random again to choose which question to pick
        long random = Math.round((Math.random() * numberOfQuestions) + 1);
        //We pull they keySet from the map and use the random number as index, this is our question now
        problem = questions.keys().get(random);
        //we use the question to pull the answer
        answer = questions.get(problem);
        //as our last step, we remove the question from the list, so it is not pulled again
        questions.remove(problem);
    }

    public String getProblem(){
        return problem;
    }

    public String getAnswer(){
        return answer;
    }

}
```

With those changes you create a new Object of *Problem* with each loop iteration. You do not know, or care, what type of arithmetic function it is, you just know it is either of the 4, and always a new question.
The only thing you have to ensure now is that you have at least 10 questions per class, when you want to have 10 questions in the quiz. Otherwise you will run into exceptions eventually.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I have learned a ton just be reading your critique and realized how simple and logical you break everything down